# Django when using python-ffmpeg-video-streaming get error The system cannot find the file specified in

Tags: python, django

In Django, I'm using `python-ffmpeg-video-streaming`.

AND this is my CODE:

```
    from django.conf import settings
    import ffmpeg_streaming
    from ffmpeg_streaming import Formats, Bitrate, Representation, Size

    video_file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + self.video_path

    video = ffmpeg_streaming.input(video_file_path + 'video.mp4')

    _480p = Representation(Size(854, 480), Bitrate(750 * 1024, 192 * 1024))
    _720p = Representation(Size(1280, 720), Bitrate(2048 * 1024, 320 * 1024))

    hls = video.hls(Formats.h264(), hls_list_size=10, hls_time=5)
    hls.representations(_480p, _720p)
    hls.fragmented_mp4()
    hls.output(video_file_path + 'hls.m3u8')
```

When I run my code, I get this error. but I can see `hls.m3u8` in file path directory.

> FileNotFoundError at /cpanel/videos/new/ [WinError 2] The system
> cannot find the file specified Request Method:    POST Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpanel/videos/new/ Django Version:    3.0.8
> Exception Type:   FileNotFoundError Exception Value:   [WinError 2] The
> system cannot find the file specified

Comment: if ```self.video_path``` doesn't have a / at the end of it, then you need to add a "/" after ```video_file_path```

Comment: yes this is the path print:
input:
C:\projects\streaming\streaming\media/video.mp4
output:
C:\projects\streaming\streaming\media/hls.m3u8

Comment: try using ```os.path.join(video_file_path, 'hls.m3u8')```  (after you've imported os)

Comment: still same error!